# How to set string value in dropdown attribute programmatically in magento 2.2.X?

Tags: magento2.2.2, dropdown-attribute

I want to set one string value to sizes attribute in drop-down ?

```
           //get sage dimension value
           $dimension = $value->Dimensions;    

            //set value
            $product->setStoreIds(array(0,1));
            $product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
            $inStock = 1;                            
            $product->setSku($product_sku);
            $product->setName($finalpname);
            $product->setAttributeSetId(4);                        
            $product->setTypeId('simple');              
            $product->setStockData(
                array(
                    'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
                    'manage_stock' => 1,
                    'is_in_stock' => $inStock,
                    'qty' => $minqty
                )
            );

             //set dimension value to sizes dropdown attribute
            $product->setSizes($dimension);

            $product->save();
```

Below attribute not set in drop-down.

> $product->setSizes($dimension);

Any idea, how can I set dimension value in sizes attribute?

output:-

[image]

Actual Output:-

[image]

Comment: Add more information

Comment: let us know in which format you are getting you `$dimension` value. Please add the array

Comment: format of dimension  <Dimensions>  2&L x 3&W  </Dimensions>

Comment: are you trying to save to product or trying to assign size attribute options?

Comment: save to product

Comment: please give me solution? I am not set dimension value in drop-down attribute .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the Size of attribute values and I have checked the post value match to the attribute list. If matched then set the value to the product

```
foreach ($result as $key=>$value) {
  if ($value['value'] == $dimension ) 
  {
    $size_option_id = $value['option_id'];
  }
}

$product->setSizes($size_option_id);
```